# Coonecting android app in device to remote server database failed

Tags: android, cordova, database-connection

I have an android app that is connected to a remote server.
The server contains some php files and a database.
When I tested my apk in emulator, it works fine.

But when it is installed on a device, it's not getting connected with the server.
That is files are not accessible to app when it runs in a device.
My manifest file is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The server is a free host web server and it is public.
Please help me to find a solution.

I am using phonegap.

Comment: Can you post the code and the logcat?

Comment: Did you add the server to your whitelist?